# Storing logical relationship with tags in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, boolean-logic

We have a list of tags in the Tag Table :

**Tag**

```
Tag1
Tag2
Tag3
```

We would like to use these tags to create a logical relationship between tags :

```
Example1 : (Tag1 AND Tag2) OR Tag1
Example2 : Tag1 OR Tag 2
Example3 : (Tag1 OR Tag2) AND Tag2
```

I would like to know what would be the best way to store the logical representations in the DB ? Is there an industry standard that Is hould be looking at while implementing the architecture ?

Comment: What are you planning to do with these relationships later?  Is there a need to detect/ignore/enforce consistency/contradiction?  (I don't have any answers yet but I'd like to understand the problem better)

Comment: Basically depending on these tags and their relations, an API will be reading them and deciding to pass on more related information.

Comment: so the relationships are in effect another row in another table (logically if not physically)?  Is the idea that the relationships are against the full collection of tags?  Or is the purpose to somehow collect a subset of the tags and find out which evaluate to true or false for that given set of tags?

Comment: The entire relation ship should be stored in such a way that when the data is queried again it should build the relation again and not just to evaluate to true or false.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not getting it. Why would you build the relationship again? Do you mean you want to store the expressions somehow and be able to evaluate the expressions against the presence or absence (or values) of the tags?

Comment: Think of these relations as configurations (settings) and some other modeule (API) reading them should be able to "remake" the relationship.

Comment: Nope.  Still no idea what you're trying to do.  You have not made it clear how these "relationships" work.  You just have a table of tags and ??????  what?  An expression?  What if the tag exists?  Does not exists?  Evaluates to true? False?  A configuration or settings file is a well understood problem with a  solution.  What's different?